# How to install powershell on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: azure, docker, powershell, ubuntu

I tried to install power-shell on ubuntu 20.04 docker image using [Azure manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/install-ubuntu?view=powershell-7.2) but I got

```
Step 10/30 : RUN wget -q "https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb"
wget: error getting response: Invalid argument
```

What I am doing wrong here?

My container OS is:

```
root@:/opt# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

Comment: remove " " from url and try ,RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi anyway the same error "Invalid argument".

Comment: Maybe it is related to "No LSB modules are available."?

Comment: Hey @Janis can you try this wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru/bin/sh: lsb_release: not found
wget: server returned error: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
The command '/bin/sh -c wget -q packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: First tell me have you updated your system packages to latest version?

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru I checked seams no.

Comment: Okay then update your version first by using this  apt-get update -y

once your version is updated try the command which you have used earlier

Comment: @SaiSakethGuduru Step 10/31 : RUN apt-get update -y
/bin/sh: apt-get: not found.  Seams we have very slim image.

Comment: try this once to upgrade  sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Comment: apt: not found and sudo too.

Comment: I think I need to use this https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-powershell

Answer (score 1):

•   The command that you are using to **install ‘Powershell’ on Ubuntu 20.04 docker image is incorrect**. ***`The correct command to install ‘Powershell’ from the Ubuntu repository is as follows`***: -

```
  wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/$(lsb_release -rs)/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

***`Once you execute the above command, the required installable files for ‘Powershell’ are downloaded and further then to install the files, execute the command below`***: -

```
 dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
```

•   Next, **update the repository with the latest changes or updates from the Microsoft Updates CDN related to ‘Powershell’ commands or features updates and install ‘Powershell’** with the help of the following commands: -

```
 apt-get update -y
 apt-get install powershell -y
```

Once the above has been done, then you can successfully **connect to the Powershell by executing the command** below: -

```
pwsh
```

For more detailed information, kindly refer the below link: -

***https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-and-use-powershell-on-ubuntu-20-04/***